# Spark streaming StreamingContext active count

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, streaming, spark-streaming

The [spark docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html) state:

> Only one StreamingContext can be active in a JVM at the same time.

Imagine a case where I am planning to read/process data from two Kafka topics, where there is one job fetching data from one Kafka topic, and another fetching data from the other kafka topic. Can I trigger these two jobs in parallel on the same hadoop cluster simultaneously?

It also states,

> Once a context has been stopped, it cannot be restarted.

So if I have to stop the spark job due to some reason, what is the way to get it restarted? Do I trigger it through oozie or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I trigger these two jobs in parallel on the same hadoop cluster
>   simultaneously?

For the sake of simplicity, lets clear up the terms. A `StreamingContext` is unique within a Spark job. If you want to read multiple streams inside *the same job*, you can do that by passing the same `StreamingContext` twice to different `KafkaUtils.createStream` methods.

If you have *multiple jobs*, which you submit to Spark, then each can have it's own `StreamingContext`. Each job will have it's own JVM instance.

> So if I have to stop the spark job due to some reason, what is the way
>   to get it restarted?

One possible way of achieving what you want is using Spark's cluster mode to run your streaming job and passing the `--supervise` flag. The Spark Master will make sure the job is restarted on failure.

You can read more on that in Sparks ["Submitting Applications"](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) documentation.